# Google Play App Signing - what is the recommended way to store an upload key?

Tags: android, security, google-play, android-keystore, android-app-signing

After you enroll in Google Play App Signing and create your upload key, where is the best location to store it (git, local, server, etc.) and with which encryption?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would depend on what is your building and releasing process.

Ideally, you would want to restrict the access only to the person/server signing the APK (or App Bundle) that will be uploaded to the Play Console.

If you have a build server, then storing the keystore on the build server with ACLs limited to that server and no other user. And you may want to consider a backup in a secure cloud folder with restricted ACLs.

You should avoid have it in your Git repository since that would make it available to any contributor of the project, most of which wouldn't need access to it.

Comment: Given that all our developers can make a signed release, making our private Git repository the most comfortable option, is it safe otherwise? Shouldn't it be encrypted?